# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue, despite all resources being on same domain

Tags: amazon-ec2, xmpp, access-control, strophe

I am writing a javascript/strophejs xmpp client, and have been so far using it to connect to a xmpp server hosted at hosted.im, via a public BOSH service (http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind). The html/javascript is also hosted online, at testserver.host56.com (not the real url).

Now, I decided to host the xmpp server on the amazon web cloud, and use my own Bosh service, hosted on this server as well.

Now, my ec2 instance is at myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (also not real url).

I also have a BOSH service up and running, at myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7070.

Finally, I have also allowed traffic to this ec2 instance through both the instances firewall and through the AWS Security Group policy.

However, when trying to connect to this instance's xmpp server (openfire), using my JS/strophejs client, I get the following message in the Chrome javascript console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7070/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is therefore not allowed access

Why am I getting this issue, if the origin is on the same domain as the requested resource?

The Ec2 instance is running Windows Server 2012.

This is the code I use to log in:

```
var conn = new Strophe.Connection("http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7070/");
conn.connect("chris@myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com", "myPassword", somecallback);
```

Thanks,

best regards,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned, even if you're on the same domain, the ports must also match otherwise CORS is required.

You may not be using the correct URL for your connection manager, all of the ones I've seen use an address ending in `/http-bind/` or similar.

Have you tried connecting with `Strophe.Connection("http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7070/http-bind/");`?

Also, you can test for the presence of the crossdomain.xml file by simply visiting `http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7070/crossdomain.xml` to ensure that CORS has been successfully enabled.

Comment: Hi Colton, thanks for your response. I think the url I am using for the Bosh service is correct as it is. When I go to http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7070 I see a page saying "Openfire HTTP Binding Service". However http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7070/http-bind/ or http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7070/crossdomain.xml both give 404 errors

Comment: Have you enabled CORS from within the Openfire configuration console? There might be something wrong with your server configuration, I'm also running an instance of Openfire and if I browse to `127.0.0.1:7070` I load a page saying "Openfire HTTP Binding Service", browsing to `127.0.0.1:7070/crossdomain.xml` loads an XML file, and browsing to `127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/` returns a 404 from jetty, but that is the address I use with `Strophe.Connection()`. Please try connecting to the full address ending in `/http-bind/`.

Comment: Hi FPS, this is what 127.0.0.1:7070/crossdomain.xml looks like:

Comment: Actually, it turned out you were right, i needed to add /http-bind/, e.g. Strophe.Connection("http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7070/http-bind/");  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The browser will not allow since the ports are different. I don't know what you have at AWS, but you can proxy the request in both direction, like as:

```
http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/http-bind/   <--------->   http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7070/
```

See item no 5: [Connecting with Strophe.js](http://expertnotfound.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/setting-up-openfire-bosh-strophe/) of the tutorial for Apache use case.

Comment: Hi Uluk, thanks for your repsonse. I came across the link you posted as well, but it didn't help me very much as it uses Ubuntu Server, and I am using Windows Server 2012. For example, the simple task of doing "sudo a2enmod proxy_http", I am not sure how to do this in windows. I cant find a2enmod anywhere in my version of apache.

Comment: I have found link http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.de/2012/08/apache-modproxy-for-windows.html, so I uncommented/loaded modules LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so 
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so 
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so in httpd.conf. Now I am supposed to put this at the end of the file: ProxyPass <proxyname> <endpointURL>

eg:

ProxyPass /foo/ http://localhost:8081/LearnJM/  Not sure what I am supposed to put for /foo and http://localhost.. etc though. Any help?

Comment: Try as `ProxyPass /http-bind http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7070/` and on the next line `ProxyPassReverse /http-bind http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7070/`. Then change your BOSH url to `http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/http-bind/`